# How to verify that Multiple Images (List of images) are visible using Playwright JavaScript

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

Locator page.locator('.inner-blocks div.img-block') returns 3 images. I want to verify one by one that all three images are visible on the Page. I am using Page Object Pattern. My page Object class looks like this

## Dashboard.js

```
class dashboardPage{
constructor(page)
{
this.ImageBlocks = page.locator('.inner-blocks div.img-block')
 }
async verifytopSectionThreeBlocks()
{
const totalblocks = await this.ImageBlocks.count()
console.log("total count:"+totalblocks)
for(let i=0;i<totalblocks;i++)
{
   
     return (await this.ImageBlocks.nth(i))
}
}
}
module.exports ={dashboardPage};
```

And in the test class i am trying to assert that all images are visible.

```
const result = dashboardpage.verifytopSectionThreeBlocks()
 await expect (result).toBeVisible()
```

This is giving error. Could anyone point it out and fix what is wrong here.

Comment: Which error is it giving, exactly? You have a typo: `except` should be `expect`. Also, your `for` loop `return`s on the first iteration. I suggest formatting your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.all()` and a loop:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

// sample page to prove example correctness
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="inner-blocks">
  <div class="img-block"></div>
  <div class="img-block"></div>
  <div class="img-block"></div>
</div>
<script>

// make the elements visible after 2 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".img-block").forEach(e => {
    e.textContent = "added";
  });
}, 2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>`;

test("all image blocks are eventually visible", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const imageBlocks = page.locator(".inner-blocks div.img-block");
  await expect(imageBlocks).toHaveCount(3);

  for (const imageBlock of await imageBlocks.all()) {
    await expect(imageBlock).toBeVisible();
  }
});
```

In a POM:

```js
// ... same sample HTML and imports

class DashboardPage {
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.imageBlocks = page.locator(".inner-blocks div.img-block");
  }

  goto() {
    return this.page.setContent(html); // for testing; replace with goto
  }

  get topSectionBlocks() {
    return this.imageBlocks;
  }
}

// ...

test("3 image blocks are eventually visible", async ({page}) => {
  const dashboard = new DashboardPage(page);
  await dashboard.goto();
  await expect(dashboard.topSectionBlocks).toHaveCount(3);

  for (const block of await dashboard.topSectionBlocks.all()) {
    await expect(block).toBeVisible();
  }
});
```

A few notes:

- `return` ends the function, breaking the loop at the first iteration.
- Avoid `count()`/`nth()`.
- `except` should be `expect`.
- Always format code so it's readable.
- Class names should always be UpperPascalCase, not camelCase. Similarly, `this.ImageBlocks` should be camelCase instead of UpperPascalCase, so `this.imageBlocks`.
- `verifytopSectionThreeBlocks` doesn't actually verify anything, just retrieves locators. I'd call it `topSectionBlocks` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the loop with a return statement; however, functions can only return one value. This means that your loop will perform only one iteration and stop afterward because the function's execution will conclude. As a result, you will always receive only the first image.

Try running this code to confirm:

```js
function test() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    return i
  }
}

console.log(test())
```

To check all images, you can modify the code to return an array of images. Then, within the test, you can iterate through the array to perform the necessary checks.

```js
const imageBlocks = page.locator('.inner-blocks div.img-block');

for (const imageBlock of await imageBlocks.all()) {
  await expect(imageBlock).toBeVisible();
}
```